# Finding the Index while searching from an Array using in_array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My aim is to find out what the operator is, and where it was in the original $operatorArray (which contains the various operators such as "+", "-" etc... )

So I have managed to check when $operator matches with another operator in my existing $operatorArray, however I need to know where in $operatorArray it is found.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['explodedQ'] as $operator){ //search through the user input for the operator. 

        if (in_array("$operator", $operatorArray)) { //if the operator that we found is in the array, then tell us what it is

            print_r("$operator"); //prints the operator found
            print_r("$positionNumber"); //prints where the operator is

        } //if operator 
        else{

            $positionNumber++; //The variable which keeps count on where the array is searching. 
        }
```

I've tried Google/Stack searching, but the thing is, I don't actually know what to Google search. I've searched for things like "find index from in_array" etc... and I can't see how to do it. If you could provide me with a simple way to understand how to achieve this, I would be greatful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: DO NOT use variables as you do it here. Remove double quotes NOW !

Comment: Ok, can you tell me why? (I'm still learning actually) :) Is it because it's unnecessary and just makes it longer or a technical reason? or both?

Comment: it's always better to avoid doble quotes - even in printing variable. It's much cleaner, quicker (minimally but still) for PHP parser, avoids misspellings, better IDEs support and so on.. If you will continue quotes-usage of variables it will be harder for you to change programming language, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken straight from the PHP manual:

[`array_search()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) - Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

If you're searching a non-associative array, it returns the corresponding key, which is the index you're looking for. For non-consecutively indexed arrays (i.e. `array(1 => 'Foo', 3 => 'Bar', ...)`) you can use the result of `array_values()` and search in it.

Comment: I found that this was the best answer. All the other answers were similar, however this one explains it nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will do what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this a try

```
foreach($_SESSION['explodedQ'] as $index => $operator) { /* your stuff */ }
```

That way you can print the `$index` as soon as your `in_array()` hits the right `$operator`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need [array_search()](http://php.net/array_search)

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$key = array_search($operator, $array);
```